# Как работают с БД у вас?

Tags: база-данных

Начал изучение бд, и возник вопрос: Как управляются с БД на работе?
Используют графический интерфейс? или через Command Line (в слачае MySQL).
Вопрос задаю потому-что есть-ли смысл углубляться в консольные команды, если существуют удобные графические редакторы для этого.

Comment: Раньше использовал phpmyadmin. Сейчас перешел на клиент: heidiSQL. Вам всё равно придется изучить синтаксис для составления выражений. Клиенты служат скорее для того, чтобы посмотреть данные.

Comment: использую phpmyadmin, настроил его для работы с несколькими серверами, удобно и кроссплатформенно, ставить ничего не надо, только браузер нужен. Другими бд не особо пользовался, но всегда находил вебгуи под базы данных) webом удобнее, независишь от твоего места работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от задач.

Отлаживать запросы, смотреть данные, менять структуру БД, разумеется, лучше через графический интерфейс.

А вот выполнять админские задачи - через консоль. Здесь: создание БД, резервное копирование, разворачивание БД из дампа, накат обновлений предварительно собранных в sql-скрипты и прочее.

Answer (score 2):

По сути СУБД в контексте БД что консольного типа что графического пересекаются. Что так, что так нужно создавать запросы. Разница только в представлении данных, по мне так что удобнее тем и пользоваться. А ориентироваться при любом подходе (консоль, графика) изходя из опыта одинаково легко!

Так что решайте сами Лэвэла они оба дают одинаково правда графика даёт +100 к скорости!))